# Как сделать EditText не активным по умолчанию

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/famil"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Фамилия"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
```

и если зайти в приложение, то в этом поле мигает курсор, и появляется клавиатура.
как можно сделать чтоб это происходило только тогда, когда пользователь нажал на это поле ввода? и чтоб если после того как появилась клавиатура, и пользователь коснулся в любой области экрана(за пределами EditText) клавиатура и курсор в поле ввода чтоб пропали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения желаемого результата вам нужно сделать несколько вещей. 
Во первых в разметке корневой layout использовать для перехватa события нажатия на экран и скрытия клавиатуры. Понадобиться id-шник

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/touch_interceptor"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/famil"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_reg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Фамилия"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        <!-- что-нить ещё-->
  </FrameLayout>
```

В классе соответственно для FrameLayout-а и EditText-а прописываете логику включения/отключения EditText-а следующим образом:

```
    YourActivity extends Activity {

       private EditText etFamil;
       private FrameLayout interceptor;


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         interceptor = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.touch_interceptor)
         etFamil = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.famil)

         interceptor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                   etFamil.setFocusable(false);
                }
                return v.performClick();
              }
         });
         etFamil.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                  v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
               }
               return v.performClick();
            }
         });
      }

    }
```